# Ensure entity is added to hibernate search index

Tags: java, hibernate-search

We currently have a process that can be summarized as follows:

1. Insert list of entity A from batch load process.
2. Update the status of those entities after a specified date has passed.

We use hibernate search to index some of the properties of entity A. However, we also have a requirement that we don't index the entity until the status has been updated.

Currently, we check at indexing time with an **EntityIndexingInterceptor** whether or not to exclude the entity based on its status.

The problem is we don't index the status field itself - so when it changes, hibernate's transparent mechanism of adding it to the index isn't applied, and it isn't ever added.

Is there a better way of being able to force hibernate to add it to the index without adding the field itself to the index? We currently rebuild the index nightly which is usually OK but still leaves a window where an entity may not be searchable until the next rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? Dirty checking optimization should be automatically disabled when using interceptors:

> Dirty checking optimization is disabled when interceptors are used. Dirty checking optimization does check what has changed in an entity and only triggers an index update if indexed properties are changed. The reason is simple, your interceptor might depend on a non indexed property which would be ignored by this optimization.

(From [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-indexinginterceptor))

If it isn't, please report the issue with a reproducer, or at least mentioning the exact version of Hibernate Search/Hibernate ORM you are using: [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/), [test case templates](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search)

Until we fix this (if it's actually a bug), you can always disable the dirty checking optimization explicitly:

```
hibernate.search.enable_dirty_check false
```

Comment: D'oh - thank you for pointing this out to me. I investigated a bit further and it seems to perform the update we are actually bypassing hibernate entirely (raw update statement), which I wasn't aware of.. So, this shouldn't be an issue with hibernate search at all.